# iOS TableView Gradient Effect

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have seen many tutorials about how to apply a gradient effect to a cell of a TableView but what I wanted to achieve was for a user to select a base color and then create a gradient effect across all the cells of the table. Similar to this:

http://realmacsoftware.com/clear/

If anyone has any ideas about how to achieve this, that would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will just have to calculate each color in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: and set it there.

some fake code i whipped up to give you an idea.

```
- (UIColor *)colorForRow:(NSInteger)row withTotalRows:(NSInteger)totalRows {
// code to calculate the colors, you can use total rows to insure the end color.
// You will want to calculate the percentage of each color for your gradient.

    return color;
} 

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Get your cell first

    NSInteger totalRows = [self numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorForRow:indexPath.row withTotalRows:totalRows];

}
```